# How to install PHP extension using PECL (with Homebrew)

Tags: php, rabbitmq, homebrew, pecl

I try to install amqp php extension on my mac using brew.

**Enviroment:** MacOS Catalina 10.15.6,
Homebrew 2.5.0, PHP 7.4.10, rabbitmq 3.8.8, rabbitmq-c 0.10.0

I got following messages after executing: pecl install amqp

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking for amqp using pkg-config... configure: error: librabbitmq not found
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/amqp/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-librabbitmq-dir' failed
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone with similar problem.

For the question:

Set the path to librabbitmq install prefix [autodetect] :

**do not leave empty answer** (autodetect).

In my case, setting this value to

/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.10.0

do the job.

Comment: To get the path of rabbitmq-c 
`brew --prefix rabbitmq-c`